# Show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} {xy\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

> **Find the limit** $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} {xy\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

By approaching the origin along both $x,y$-axis, I got the same result $0$.

So how can I prove the limit exists by epsilon-delta definition?

Comment: Try polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have
$$\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\lt\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{y^2}}\right|=|x|$$
hence the limit exists and equals zero.

Comment: I do not quite understand why the LHS less than x can conclude the limit exists.

Comment: Because as long as $|x|\lt\epsilon$ we can ensure that the given function is also $\lt\epsilon$ so by the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, the limit exists and is zero.

Comment: Or use the more symmetric $x^2+y^2\ge\max(|x|,|y|)^2$ to get $$\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\le \min(|x|,|y|)$$ which is less singular outside the origin.

Comment: @Lutzl, your approach seems very much reasonable for me in understanding the problem at hand. If I may ask, what text did you get the concept from?

Comment: $$\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\leq\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}\to0$$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$..

Answer (score 1):

Polar coordinate gives you  $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} {xy\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{r\to 0} {r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta\over r} =$$

$$\lim _{r\to 0} r\sin \theta \cos \theta =0$$

Comment: Is it enough to prove that the limit exists?

Comment: Yes, it shows that limit exists and it is $0$u

Answer (score 1):

Because of $0\le(|x|-|y|)^2$ you get $2|xy|\le x^2+y^2$. Thus
$$
\frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2
$$
which proves continuity in $(x,y)=(0,0)$ with value $0$.